# Dgrid sorting order with special characters

Tags: sorting, dojo, special-characters, dgrid

I use dgrid (http://dgrid.io/index.php) in my application.

It has sorting implemented by default, but I would like to sort special characters such as Ą, Ę in oreder they are supposed to be in. By that i mean: A, Ą, B, C, Ć, ... 
Right now I have rows starting with special characters at the end of the grid.

Any idea how to repair it?

Comment: Of interest https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/276

Comment: Thanks, it helps perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

With help from link provided by GibboK i managed to write custom sorting in dgrid.
It works like that:

```
var grid = new (declare([Grid]))({
            store: new Memory({ data: data, idProperty: 'id' }),
            columns: columns,
        }, 'domID');

grid.on('dgrid-sort', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                grid.set('sort', function (a, b) {
                    *sorting logic*
                grid.updateSortArrow(event.sort, true);
            })
```

Comment: I am glad you have found a solution :)

Comment: Answer I provided before works but I have another problem. If dgrid uses pagination, then after changing page I have the default sorting again. Any ideas?